# apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient not uploading the file to the required folder

Tags: java, linux, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm using the following code to upload an xml file to the directory /home/domainname/public_html/guest in the server. However, the file is uploaded only to the location /home/domainname. It is not uploading to the child directories. Please advise.

FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;

```
    try {
        client.connect(Util.getProductsXMLFTPServer());
        client.login(Util.getProductsXMLFTPUser(), Util.getProductsXMLFTPPassword());

        //
        // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        //

        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Util.getProductsXMLFTPInputFilePath(), Util.getProductsXMLFTPOutputFileName()));
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(Util.getProductsXMLFTPUploadPath());


        client.storeFile(Util.getProductsXMLFTPOutputFileName(), fis);
        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code, it works. I've only changed file type declaration to binary, which may be not needed for XML files.
Here's my complete code for reference:

```
package apachenet.ftp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient(); 
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            client.connect(/*Util.getProductsXMLFTPServer()*/"127.0.0.1");
            client.login(/*Util.getProductsXMLFTPUser()*/"pwyrwinski", 
                    /*Util.getProductsXMLFTPPassword()*/"secret");
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // optional
            fis = new FileInputStream(
                    new File(/* Util.getProductsXMLFTPInputFilePath() */"/home/pwyrwinski", 
                            /* Util.getProductsXMLFTPOutputFileName() */"img.png"));
            client.changeWorkingDirectory(/*Util.getProductsXMLFTPUploadPath()*/ "someDir");


            client.storeFile(/*Util.getProductsXMLFTPOutputFileName()*/"img_bis.png", fis);
            client.logout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's roughly the same as yours. 
`Util` class calls are replaced with raw data.

When I ran it, file `/home/pwyrwinski/img.png` was uploaded to `{FTP_USER_ROOT}/someDir` directory on ftp server with name changed to `img_bis.png`. I assume this is exactly what you wanted to achieve.

Let's go back to your problem.

1. Try to check what is returned from
   `Util.getProductsXMLFTPUploadPath()` call. My guess is it's not what
   you're expecting - so debug it in your IDE or print it to the console.
2. Check if path returned from `Util.getProductsXMLFTPUploadPath()`
   call starts with slash, it shouldn't.

**UPDATE 1.**
Does direcory `/home/domainname/public_html/guest` exist on server?

Add following method to your class:

```
private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it after **every** ftp-client's method call. This will give you codes and descriptions of every command result. I suspect `client.changeWorkingDirectory(...)` ends with error, probably: `550 Permission Denied (or No such file or folder)`.

Next modification will be:

```
client.login(Util.getProductsXMLFTPUser(), Util.getProductsXMLFTPPassword());
System.out.println(client.printWorkingDirectory()); // added this line!
```

this will tell us what is current working directory after login in.

Please post your results.

Comment: I verified the path. It was correct. I tried by removing the "/" but it is still the same. Not going beyond the directory that I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. I changed the parameter to "public_html/guest" instead of "/home/domainuser/public_html/guest". Seems it tries to locate the full directory path from the current location. It was giving me an error message saying directory doesn't exist. Thanks a lot again. It worked like magic.

Answer (score 1):

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
              System.out.println("before server connection");
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            System.out.println("before user name and passwod");
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            System.out.println("connection sucess");


            // windows working fine
            File secondLocalFile = new File("/home/aims/archived_reports/tes_S_000000123/test.pdf");
//            String secondRemoteFile = "/archived_reports/PermanentRecord.pdf";

//linux
          //  File secondLocalFile = new File("/archived_reports/tes_S_000009123/test.pdf");

            String secondRemoteFile = "remotefilename.pdf";
            InputStream  inputStream = new FileInputStream(secondLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Start uploading second file");

                    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/reports");// home/ftp.test/reports folder


          System.out.println("Prasent Working Directory :"+ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());


            OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);
                 int returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
                 System.out.println(returnCode);
            byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
            int read = 1;

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            }

System.out.println();           
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
                     boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
            if (completed) {
                System.out.println("The second file is uploaded successfully.");
            }
```